# Ajax redirect based on the fragment?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

consider I have an array with some urls:

```
$array[0]='mywebsite/pagea';
$array[1]='mywebsite/pageb';
$array[2]='mywebsite/pagec';
//> please note this is the PHP array, but I can output as a javascript array without problems
```

I will output them in my `link.php`

Is there a way with jQuery to read that fragment (idX) and then redirect to the corrispondent url?

## Edit

Thinking about compatibily (browsers without javascript) now let's consdier I have this kind of link:

```
<a href="mywebsite/pagea" class="intercept">pagea</a>
<a href="mywebsite/pagea" class="intercept">pageb</a>
<a href="mywebsite/pagea" class="intercept">pagec</a>
```

For browser without javascript the link will work as normal, for every else i will do like

```
$('.intercept').onClick( function (){

  //> append the hashtag to the current url
  //> make the right redirect after some interval (ie this.href)
  //> how? xD
});
```

At this point i have only to check if the url was opened with an hashtag and make the right redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I misread your original question. Sorry.

Assuming $array is a javascript array or object.

```
   $('a').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),
            id= parseInt(url.split('#id')[1]);

        window.location = $array[id];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but I would avoid to trigger it on .click, I say this because I would trigger the redirect even if a user type in the browser that url (link.php#id1) I mean if someone opens link.php#id1 the jquery should redirect to the correct url. Anyway +1 for help

Comment: updated my answer to reflect this; if you want to trigger something based on the hash event (including first page load) the jquery bbq plugin will be the way to go.

Comment: @karl: i don't think i need to trigger an onhashchange, i need to check it only once when the page is opened, then i can check for the onClick event. (i really don't want to use other plugins)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the redirect even if someone visits the page with a hash, you want to use a hashchange event.  The [jQuery bbq plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) makes this easy to do cross browser with its [hashchange event](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#hashchange_event%28BBQ%29).

It is a pretty lightweight plugin so I doubt there's going to be much advantage to coding up something on your own that will work cross browser and you would likely end up with similar code to the bbq plugin.

Comment: I would avoid to use external plugin to do such easy thing, could you write some code example?

Comment: Hm wait a moment, I don't need that hashchange event I think... I can trigger the event on the <a onClick> so i don't have to check every interval the hash change...  I only need to change it on window.onload if someone opened the link.php already with that fragment